# Is it possible to have a collection on an object that does not have a foreign key relationship to each other?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using an declarative SQLAlchemy class to perform computations.  Part of the computations require me to perform the computations for all configurations provided by a different table which doesn't have any foreign key relationships between the two tables.

This analogy is nothing like my real application, but hopefully will help to comprehend what I want to happen.

I have a set of cars and a list of paint colors.
The car object has a factory which provides a car in all possible colors

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlachemy.orm import *

def PaintACar(car, color):
   pass

Base = declarative_base()

class Colors(Base):
    __table__ = u'colors'

    id = Column('id', Integer)
    color= Column('color', Unicode)

class Car(Base):
    __table__ = u'car'

    id = Column('id', Integer)
    model = Column('model', Unicode)

    # is this somehow possible?
    all_color_objects = collection(...)

    # I know this is possible, but would like to know if there's another way
    @property
    def all_colors(self):
        s = Session.object_session(self)
        return s.query(A).all()

    def CarColorFactory(self):
        for color in self.all_color_objects:
            yield PaintACar(self, color)
```

My question:  Is it possible to produce all_color_objects somehow?  Without having to resort to finding the session and manually issuing a query as in the all_colors property?

Comment: All due respect, why are you trying to relate something that has no relation? Smells like anti-design pattern to me.

Comment: what better way would there be here besides getting a Session and producing the query you want?  Are you looking for being able to add to the collection and that automatically flushes things?  (just add the objects to the Session?)  Do you not like using object_session(self) (you can build some mixin class or something that hides that for you?)   It's not really clear what the problem is.  The objects here have no relationship to the parent class so there's no particular intelligence SQLAlchemy would be able to add.

Comment: @zzeek.  That's basically it - dislike of object_session(self), but if you're not ranting about that, suggesting mixin classes, I guess I can live with it.  If you make that as the answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, so I'm providing the best answer I saw (as a comment by zzzeek).  Basically, I was looking for one-off syntactic sugar.  My original 'ugly' implementation works just fine.

> what better way would there be here besides getting a Session and producing the query you
>   want? Are you looking for being able to add to the collection and that automatically
>   flushes things? (just add the objects to the Session?) Do you not like using
>   object_session(self) >(you can build some mixin class or something that hides that for 
>   you?) It's not really clear >what the problem is. The objects here have no relationship to
>   the parent class so there's no particular intelligence SQLAlchemy would be able to add. 
>   – zzzeek Jun 17 at 5:03